# Prove $2^e$ is transcendental

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I remembered that a Russian mathematician proved this, but now I cannot find it again.

Could you please recommend a book on these kinds of problems?

Comment: I like Niven, Irrational Numbers

Comment: well, I don't see anything that would imply your idea, i think you have remembered it incorrectly.

Comment: @WillJagy It's an open question if $2^e$ is irrational...

Comment: A Russian mathematician proved that $2^\sqrt2$ is transcendental, but that's another story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unknown if $2^e$ is irrational. [See here (under Open questions).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number)

> It is not known whether $\pi e, \frac\pi e, 2^e, e^e, e^{e^e}, π^\sqrt{2}, \ln π$, Catalan's constant, or the Euler–Mascheroni gamma constant γ are irrational.

(Remark: All real numbers that are transcendental are irrational.)